# How do I dynamically add columns to Vaadin 7 Table?

Tags: java, vaadin

I have string arrays (String[] foos) that may have anywhere from 1 to 50 items that I want to lay across rows in a Vaadin 7.0 Table, when a button is clicked. I don't know how many columns the table will need before the button is clicked. so I don't know how many containerPropeties (table.addContainerProperty) are needed.

I've tried these with no luck:

```
table.addItem(foos,null);
table.addItem(foos);
```

How can I dynamically add columns when the string array has unknown number of items/columns?

Update:

I have it working somewhat using the code below, but it's cutting off the last four columns of data...

```
wip = new ArrayList<String>();

            Table t = new Table ();

            for (String foo:wip){
                int totalWip = wip.size();
                System.out.println(totalWip);
                String[] foos = StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator(StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(foo), "->"); //put row in array

                 //get total number of items in the row                 
                System.out.println(foos.length);

                for (int v=0; v<foos.length; v++){ //add columns to table
                    String col = "COL_" + v + "";
                    t.addContainerProperty(col, String.class, "--");                    

                }       
                for (int z=0; z<wip.size(); z++){ 
                    String row = "ROW_" + z + "";
                    t.addItem(foos, row);
                }

            }
```

Any thoughts as to why it would be cutting off the last 4 columns of data?

Comment: So having  `class Foo() { String name,description; }` would generate columns `Name` & `Description`?

Comment: Check my updates^

Comment: My first question is, why are you using `Table` if you could use `Grid`?
Besides that, so, `wip` stores all your rows and `foos` all those values?
Maybe you should keep track of which properties you have already added.